# Question considered off-topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic, allowed-topics, on-topic

Why is this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1023417/create-a-domain-gpo-with-cmd-only) considered off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where Stack Exchange's desire to be nicer leads to confusion.  I forget the explanation of why it's nicer, but details of why a question was closed are hidden from anyone with less than 3000 reputation.  You see this short explanation:

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> Want to improve this question? Update the question so it's on-topic for Server Fault.

A longer explanation of why it's closed is shown to people who are able to cast close and re-open votes and would have answered your question:

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.
>
> Closed 3 days ago by Greg Askew, Swisstone, Dave M, womble♦.
>
> (Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)

Comment: Actually, [the off-topic reasons have been upgraded](https://serverfault.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons) and some mods have initiated a discussion on their meta sites to personalize the messages, though the public-to-all "close description" is empty by default since the migration to the new design, and mods also need to deactivate the current reason to modify it...

Answer (score 5):

Because trying to use a non-powershell command line on a 17 year old, unsupported Windows server is the poster child for the *reasonable information technology management practices* close reason.